# Issue with configure_traits when using Enthought Canopy

Tags: python-2.7, enthought, traits, canopy, traitsui

I was following the tutorial "Writing a graphical applications for scientific programming using TraitsUI 
http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html
and tested the following code snippet:

```
from enthought.traits.api import *
from enthought.traits.ui.api import *

class Camera(HasTraits):
    """ Camera object """

    gain = Enum(1, 2, 3,
        desc="the gain index of the camera",
        label="gain", )

    exposure = CInt(10,
        desc="the exposure time, in ms",
        label="Exposure", )

    def capture(self):
        """ Captures an image on the camera and returns it """
        print "capturing an image at %i ms exposure, gain: %i" % (
            self.exposure, self.gain )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    camera = Camera()
    camera.configure_traits()
    camera.capture()
```

If I run this at the command line it works as advertised.  A GUI pops up.  You adjust the parameters, and when you click "OK" it returns the modified values.  But when I run the same code from within the Canopy editor by clicking the run button the default parameters print immediately; then the window pops up. When you then adjust the parameters in the GUI and click "OK" the GUI exits but the new parameter values don't print.

It is as if somehow camera.capture() is running before camera.configure_traits.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest using this newer version of the tutorial: http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html

The one you linked to references materials for TraitsUI version 3, whereas the one above is for the version you're likely using (version 4). The newer tutorial uses the newer module names, `traitsui.api` instead of `enthought.traits.ui.api` for example.

As to why Canopy displays the values immediately, this is the expected behavior when running the program:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    camera = Camera()
    camera.configure_traits()
    camera.capture()
```

When run as `__main__` (i.e., not imported as a module by another script), the script does these three things in order: creates an instance of Camera(), pops up the GUI (configure_traits), and then executes the `capture` method that prints the current values (which are "1" and "10" by default).

The OK/Cancel buttons are not hooked into setting these values. As a test, try changing the exposure or gain but instead of clicking the buttons, try inspecting these attributes from within Canopy's IPython prompt while the GUI is still open: `camera.gain` or `camera.exposure` should return the newly set values.